# Show/hide UIToolbar, "match finger movement", precisely as in for example iOS7 Safari

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitoolbar

## Note: check out Thuy's great subclass of UINavBar here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720359/294884

If you're working on this problem, GTScrollNavigationBar is close to a ready-made solution to the navBar problem!

For example: on a 2014 iPhone, open Safari, load any web page.

Look at the iOS toolbar at the bottom.

Now move your finger up and down **ONLY A FEW PIXELS**.

[image]

Basically the toolbar at the bottom, **moves with your finger**. Furthermore, the toolbar later **appears/disappears as you scroll the page**, following specific logic.

But the interaction rules are **very complicated**, and involve finger on/off during the hide, distance matching, gestures when you are further down the page, special cases for very short pages, and so on.

I want to **EXACTLY** duplicate the Apple behaviour.

(It seems sensible that we should match the Apple UX.)

Is there a way to do this?  does Apple offer a one-step command for that, which I don't know about?  Or do you have to laboriously duplicate the concept?

Thanks.

By the way, the following logic is reliable and will **roughly duplicate** the way Apple does it:

```
-(void)feedIsScrolled:(CGFloat)scrollNewOverallYPosition
{
// call this routine when scrollViewDidScroll:

self.feedIsScrolledDelta =
 scrollNewOverallYPosition - self.feedIsScrolledPrevious;
self.feedIsScrolledPrevious =
 scrollNewOverallYPosition;

// nb, you do those only in this routine, NOT the following routine.

if ( scrollNewOverallYPosition < 15.0 )
    {
    .. animate in the bar
    return;
    }

if ( self.feedIsScrolledDelta > 0.0 )
    .. animate away the bar
}

-(void)feedIsThrown:(CGFloat)scrollNewOverallYPosition
{
// call this routine when scrollViewDidEndDragging:
// BUT ONLY when willDecelerate: is true

if ( self.feedIsScrolledDelta <= 0.0 )
    .. animate in the bar
else
    .. animate away the bar
}
```

By the way, of course you can use

```
(void)setToolbarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to slide a UIToolbar up and down.  BUT that does not help in any way with "finger matching".

Note: and here for example is a superb solution seen on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21049991/294884

You could program like that, implementing each and every rule in the Apple example, to suit your taste on each point. (What to do when you are near the bottom, finger up, which direction, etc etc.)  My point is I just assumed someone must have done all that work already of **matching the Apple UX exactly** -- heh!

Comment: Is it not inerrant behaviour in a uiwebview ?

Comment: Hi Raster -- hmm, I don't think so, no.  It has no connection to UIWebView.  You would **trigger** this on any scroll view.

Comment: I didn't downvote btw. I doubt there's any one line magic command that will replicate this - it's probably buried deep in Apple's iOS framework code. Which means you will have to manually implement. Still I wait to stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks for linking to that other post. You call my solution an "ad hoc" attempt, but what else could it be? I mean, all we can do is try to match the behavior that we see.

Comment: Note also that there's nothing really special about it being a `UIToolbar` or, in my case, a `UINavigationBar`. I've implemented similar behavior for an app at work that hides a custom view as the user scrolls. The concept is actually pretty straightforward. It's just a matter of tuning it to your taste.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no open-source that does this, but I don't see it as that difficult to implement. It may be somewhat more difficult to have the exact 1:1 behavior as Safari, but it can still be done.

MobileSafar can be attached to in the debugger and, using breakpoints and the Objective C runtime, debugged and reverse engineered.

For example, your two assumptions that no toolbar and navigation bars are used are incorrect.

Here is the view hierarchy before scrolling:

http://pastebin.com/aRXr7b5Z

And after scrolling:

http://pastebin.com/CasBNuxq

As you can see, the bars have been moved from their normal location.

Breaking on `-[BrowserToolbar setFrame:]`, here is the stack trace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2332c, 0x000000010003fa70 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function1519$$MobileSafari, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 8.1
  * frame #0: 0x000000010003fa70 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function1519$$MobileSafari
    frame #1: 0x0000000100023e51 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function825$$MobileSafari + 1338
    frame #2: 0x00000001000268da MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function871$$MobileSafari + 55
    frame #3: 0x000000010009856a MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function3864$$MobileSafari + 388
    frame #4: 0x0000000100098996 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function3871$$MobileSafari + 154
    frame #5: 0x000000010002ba89 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function990$$MobileSafari + 209
    frame #6: 0x0000000102396a8c UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 55
    frame #7: 0x000000010238692b UIKit`-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 628
    frame #8: 0x000000010238ab00 UIKit`-[UIScrollView _updatePanGesture] + 1989
    frame #9: 0x0000000102644002 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 188
    frame #10: 0x0000000102642f68 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 357
    frame #11: 0x0000000102647319 UIKit`___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 53
    frame #12: 0x00000001026472a1 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 257
    frame #13: 0x000000010263f377 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 93
    frame #14: 0x0000000102353e55 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
    frame #15: 0x0000000102354b14 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 909
    frame #16: 0x000000010232c6da UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    frame #17: 0x0000000102319f2d UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    frame #18: 0x0000000100573f21 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #19: 0x00000001005737f2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    frame #20: 0x000000010058f66f CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 767
    frame #21: 0x000000010058ef83 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #22: 0x00000001011a0f04 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #23: 0x000000010231c273 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1010
    frame #24: 0x00000001000518d2 MobileSafari`___lldb_unnamed_function1998$$MobileSafari + 1558
```

So it all happens after a notification of scrolling.

I put a breakpoint on `MobileSafari'___lldb_unnamed_function990$$MobileSafari` and to get the `self` variable, print `po $arg1`. This is where all the magic happens:

http://pastebin.com/kjAXKKTW

If you are really interested in 1:1 replication, you can put breakpoints on these methods and investigate. Good luck!

Comment: Had to use pastebin because those stack traces and `_methodDescription` were too long.

Comment: dear leo natan, since you're a Genius you may be interested in this one ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008843 (Very surprisingly nobody has addressed the issue, must be an absolutely common need now, that UX concept!)  Cheers and thanks again for this here!

Answer (score 1):

I just pulled a request to GTScrollNavigationBar that helps getting the right "match finger movement". The trick is just to adjust ContentInsets according to scrollbar's frame.

It's probably not yet perfect, but it does what you look for:
https://github.com/luugiathuy/GTScrollNavigationBar/pull/21

Answer (score 0):

I used the next code to hide tabBar like in safari app. Maybe you or other people can use it with toolBar.

```
static CGFloat navBarOriginY = 20.0;
```

Create constant for base value of navigation bar origin Y position

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true;
[self.navigationController.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];
}
```

Add your custom selector to handle system swipe gesture that will fire before navBar become hidden and during hiding

```
- (void)swipe:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

//If gesture state ended/canceled or failed you need entirely change frame of tabBar

    CGRect finalFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y < 0) {
         //Tab bar will be hidden
        finalFrame.origin.y = self.maxTabBarY;
    } else {
         //Tab bar will be visible
        finalFrame.origin.y = self.minTabBarY;
    }

    [self setFrameForTabBar:finalFrame animationDuration:0.3];

} else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

//If state == changed than you need to pan your tabBar with navBar like in safari app.

    CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    CGFloat delta = navBarOriginY - self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.presentationLayer.frame.origin.y;
    frame.origin.y = self.minTabBarY + delta;
    [self setFrameForTabBar:frame animationDuration:0.0];
} } }

- (void)setFrameForTabBar:(CGRect)frame animationDuration:(CGFloat)duration {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
});
```